# Why is the code to insert into a BST not working?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am coding up insertion into a BST in C. When I traverse the tree, the first snippet seems ineffective. I can't understand why does it not work.
This doesn't work:

```
    void insert(Node* temp, int data)
{
    if(temp==NULL)
    temp=Newnode(data);
    else if(data<temp->data)
         insert(temp->left,data);
    else if(data>temp->data)
         insert(temp->right,data);

}
```

This works:

```
Node* insert(Node* temp, int data)
{
    if(data<temp->data)
      if(temp->left!=NULL) insert(temp->left,data);
      else temp->left= Newnode(data);
    else if(data>temp->data)
       if(temp->right!=NULL) insert(temp->right,data);
       else temp->right= Newnode(data);
}
```

NOTE: I have used #define Node struct node. Newnode() allocates a new node and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at what happens when you pass in `NULL` as a root value:

`temp` is being assigned a new node instance. However, the assignment is only local to `insert()` so after the call returns the assignment is "gone".

You might want to change your insert method signature to
       `void insert(Node **temp, data)`
and use 
`*temp = Newnode(data);`
to make it work as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the second way isn't correct as well. For the two ways you posted:

1. There is problem with recursion end condition. When temp is NULL, the code creates a new Node. However there is no way that the newly created node can be attached to the parent in BST.
2. The function return type is Node*, but there is no explicit code doing the returning. Although by default C would take the return from Newnode as return value for Insert, it's not correct.

Here are two versions:

```
void insert(node **curr, int val) {
    if(!(*curr)) {
        *curr = Newnode(val);
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*curr)->data) {
        insert(&(*curr)->left, val);
    } else if(val > (*curr)->data) {
        insert(&(*curr)->right, val);
    }
}

insert(&root, val);
```

This one passes double pointer to solve the above mentioned problem.

```
Node* insert(node *curr, int val) {
    if(!curr) {
        return Newnode(val);
    }

    if(val < curr->data) {
        curr->left = insert(curr->left, val);
    } else if(val > curr->data) {
        curr->right = insert(curr->right, val);
    }

    return curr;
}

root = insert(root, val);
```

This one uses return val assignment as solution.